# Hover effect menu responsive inline

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

I'm developing a responsive site with a horizontal menu and hover css effects. When mouse hover an menu option, I add padding-left and put a background image, trouble is this: http://jsfiddle.net/khneM/1/

My menu:

```
<nav class="menu-principal-container">
    <ul>
        <li ><a title="LA FIRMA" href="#"> LA FIRMA </a>
        </li>
        <li ><a title="DESPACHO" href="#">DESPACHO</a>
        </li>
        <li ><a title="SERVICIOS" href="#">SERVICIOS</a>
        </li>
        <li ><a title="GALERÍA" href="#">GALERÍA</a>
        </li>
        <li ><a title="VARIOS" href="#">VARIOS</a>
        </li>
        <li ><a title="CONTACTO" href="#">CONTACTO</a>
        </li>
        <li ><a title="LOGIN" href="#">LOGIN</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
.menu-principal-container {
    float: left;
    width: 514px;
    margin: 1%;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #979797;
}
li:hover {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    border-color: #FFCE3B;
    text-align: right;
    background: url('http://abogados.drapps.info/wp-content/themes/araluce/img/services.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

In little width, on mouse hover last option, it  goes down doing impossible to click it

Does anybody have any idea about doing this?

Any idea would be appreciate!!!

Thank you

Comment: Increase width of `.menu-principal-container`

Comment: I cannot do this, because width is set for device width. This is a responsive menu...

Comment: Have you tried adding `min-width` property to container?(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtkUZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, Its hard to do this.. You must set a fixed width to li options menu, to do this and forget css animation.

Comment: Sure? It must exists some responsive menu with this kind of animation... some clue?

Comment: I found one solution... fixed li: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/W5Tzv/2/ what do you think?

Comment: Useful, not exactly what I wanted but It is useful for me... thank you so much! positive vote!

Answer (score 0):

just apply the padding with this rule

```
li:hover a {
  padding-left: 23px;   
}
```

and remove it from `li:hover`. (probably you may need to define the animation of the padding-left even for your links)

example: http://jsfiddle.net/32MFQ/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer... but I don't find the point you want me to understand because "login" goes down as my example... Could you explain some better? Sorry for my nonsense about this...

Comment: "In little width, on mouse hover last option, it goes down doing impossible to click it" - in your example, if you hover an option from left the pointer disappear.

Comment: I am meaning about "login" option, when mouse hover it, that option goes next line: try click "Login option" here: http://jsfiddle.net/32MFQ/1/ Thanks for your patience!!!